# can't fetch a specific API in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

My component can't fetch data from a specific API.
I am using react, and I installed react-router-dom.

**This is my App component**

```
import Recipe from "./components/Recipe";
import RecipeItself from "./components/RecipeItself";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/recipes" element={<Recipe />} />
        <Route path="/recipes/:id" element={<RecipeItself />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to fetch data from an API.
I made a component fetching the API, and when I clicked on a div in the component, I should move to another component using router..

But it doesn't work properly. The page couldn't read the response from fetch.
So I put another API and checked that it was working. So I put my original API and it worked but when I entered the component from the previous one, it didn't!

I add pictures of my console when it failed and when it is done after replacing the API. So weird
[When it failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trnYu.png)
[When I replaced the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2vON.png)

I am almost getting crazy. Can someone teach me?

**It is the first component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function RecipeCard(props) {
  // console.log(
  //   "name",
  //   props.api.name,
  //   "recipes",
  //   props.api.recipes,
  //   "then what?",
  //   props.api,
  //   "instructions1",
  //   props.api.instructions
  // );
  return (
    // Here put `link to` and give unique ids to move
    <Link to={`/recipes/${props.api.id}`}>
      <div className="recipe_card">
        <div
          className="recipe_img"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.api.thumbnail_url})` }}
        />
        <h1>{props.api.name}</h1>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
}

function RecipeApi(props) {
  const searchedOne = props.search;

  const [api, setApi] = useState([]);
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_RECIPE_API_KEY,
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "tasty.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://tasty.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/list?from=0&size=20&q=$${searchedOne}`,
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => setApi([...response.results]))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, [searchedOne]);

  return (
    <section className="recipe_api">
      <h2 className="recepe_api_title">Here are the recipes for you!</h2>
      <div className="recipe_api_boxes">
        {searchedOne.length > 0 &&
          api.map((api) => <RecipeCard key={api.id} api={api} />)}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default React.memo(RecipeApi);
```

**It is the problematic component which isn't working properly**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function RecipeItself() {
  // the url of this page should be /id
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [cont, setCont] = useState([]);

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_RECIPE_API_KEY,
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "tasty.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1"
// It didn't work well so I put a starwars API to check it :/
      //   `https://tasty.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/get-more-info?id=${id}`,
      //   options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => setCont(response))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  console.log(cont);
  //   let step = cont.instructions;
  //   console.log(step);
  //   let ingr = cont.sections[0].components;
  //   console.log(ingr);

  return (
    <div className="recipe_itself">
      <>
        {/* <div
          className="recipe_itself_img"
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${cont.thumbnail_url})` }}
        />
        <h2 className="recipe_itself_name">{cont.name}</h2>
        <div className="recipe_itself_cont">
          <div className="recipe_itself_ingr">
            <h3>Ingredients</h3>
            <p>{cont.yields}</p>
            {ingr.map((ingr) => (
              <ul key={ingr.id}>
                <li>{ingr.raw_text}</li>
              </ul>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="redipe_itself_inst">
            <h3>Instructions</h3>
            {step.map((step) => (
              <div key={step.id}>
                <h4>Step {step.position}</h4>
                <p>{step.display_text}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div> */}
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 0)` seems like the data being returned from your api is not loaded into state correctly. Can you post an example of the returned data from the recipe api

Comment: It should have been like this :/ ( I just replaced the API from starwars one again )
`{buzz_id: 4745349, video_url: 'https://vid.tasty.co/output/77456/hls24_1518119323.m3u8', compilations: Array(2), sections: Array(1), beauty_url: null, …}` The whole data is too long so I show part of this

Comment: Was it this line that is commented out, `let ingr = cont.sections[0].components;`? It's the only place in the code I see trying to read any property `"0"`. Is the `cont` state supposed to be an array or an object? It appears the code doesn't know what it is trying to access.

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you for further thought about my code. But it is such weird. Although the `cont.sections` is an array that has 4 objects in it, I can't delete `[0]`. If I do so, console shows me `undefined`. And the code is such random. I was working on css about this page, but when I tried to show you the `ingr` without `[0]` it made error again. And I couldn't see the page again even though I activated the commented code. It seems like it can't fetch the API properly randomly. I am stuck with this..

Comment: Use null-checks/guard-clauses or optional chaining prior to accessing into potentially undefined objects/properties, e.g. `cont.sections?.[0]?.components`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice... I am still working on this and I found out something. The API fetching doesn't work when I clicked the `div` that `linked` to the component I want to see, but when I activated only `cont` ( which is a state set by fetching ) it shows me cont in console after a while, and then I can see other elements after activating other things like `step` and `ingr`. When I do like this I don't see any `[0]` error. I think the fetching code is kinda slow to fetch things. Do you know something about this ? How can I make it show a component when it is fully ready?

Comment: So sorry for my flooding questions. And appreciate to you

Comment: Add id param to useeffect dependency it will call api everytime you render component <RecipeItself />

Comment: Thank you. I used `await` here and let it set states only when it is done fetching data. But I will try what you told me too. Tysm